# Specflow steps with await for async API

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit, bdd, specflow

We're trying to get the following scenrio step to break the test in case failure happens within `DoAyncStuff()` method:

```
[Given(@"There is something")]
public async Task GivenSomething()
{
    await DoStuff();
}

private async Task DoStuff()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    throw new ApplicationException("Boom");
}
```

But it actually makes a happy green-run until you use `.Wait()` or `.Result`:

```
[Given(@"There is something")]
public void GivenSomething()
{
    DoStuff().Wait();
}
```

The problem seems to be in the NUnit generated-spec which looks like this:

```
public virtual void SomethingAsync()
{
    ...
    testRunner.Given("There is something", ...);
    ...
}
```

which seems to work with the following code:

```
public virtual async Task SomethingAsync()
{
    ...
    await this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
    ...
}
```

The code above is manually edited auto-generated file, so I'm actually looking for a way to produce following code automatically.

[The documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Testing-Silverlight-Asynchronous-Code/) seems to be the only option available for asyncronous API but it's actually for Silverlight and as far as I understand uses some kind of API, while we'd preffer to use native C# await keyword.

Is there a way to handle natively `async/await` is SpecFlow steps?

Comment: have a look at [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/647) release

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the current released version (2.1) version there is no support for async and await, support was added (via [this merged PR](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/647)) in v2.2 which is available from the [CI server](https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/specflow-ci), but there is not an official release yet.

**[EDIT]**

2.2 has been released and supports async await in tests.

Comment: Is there any update on this?, I installed the 2017 version of specflow and it doesn't seem to generate async tests, But the version of the specflow nuget is 2.2.   From the generated code it says the generator is 2.0

Comment: Have the same problem in VS2017 and SpecFlow 2.2.0 with xUnit 2.2.0. Async Tests(the part I write, not the autogenerated code) are not awaited and the flow immediately goes to next steps.

Comment: I'm running SpecFlow 2.2.0 and SpecFlow.xUnit 2.2.0 in VS 2017 and it works as expected.  Maybe post as a question @SkorunkaFrantišek :-)

Comment: I am using VS 2015 with SpecFlow 2.2.1 and when I decorate a step with async and use await inside, it goes to the next step. So for now I am using .Result in my async call.

Comment: @VargaTamas did you ensure your step uses `async Task` signature? I'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: That was exactly the problem - the signature has to be async Task and then it works, I just forgot to update, thanks for the hint.