# GetAsync returns null when used in other tests

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automated-tests, specflow

I'm new to **C#** and **.NET**, and when writing a test using **SpecFlow**, I get the error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Apparently, when I try to access the "**Response**" in the other test methods the object is **null**, but I don't know why.

I searched here, and the questions I found ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247091/getasync-request-returns-null-content) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)) don't solve my problem.

My step file:

```cs
[Binding]
public sealed class UsersSteps
{
    private HttpResponseMessage Response { get; set; } = null!;
    private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

    [Given(@"I access the users route (.*)")]
    public async void GivenIAccessTheUsersRoute(string baseUrl)
    {
        var url = new Uri(baseUrl);
        Response = await Client.GetAsync(url);

        Console.WriteLine(">> Here it works: " + Response.StatusCode);
    }

    [Then(@"I should have only 1 registered user")]
    public void ThenIShouldHaveOnlyOneRegisteredUsers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">> Does not work here: " + Response.StatusCode);
    }

    [StepDefinition(@"should be admin")]
    public void AndShouldBeAdmin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">> Does not work here: " + Response.StatusCode);
    }

    [StepDefinition(@"your name should be Fulano da Silva")]
    public void AndYourNameShouldBeFulanoDaSilva()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">> Does not work here: " + Response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

My feature file:

```
Scenario: List users
    Given I access the users route https://serverest.dev/usuarios
    Then I should have only 1 registered users
    And should be admin
    And your name should be Fulano da Silva
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SpecFlow how can I share data between steps/features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881685/in-specflow-how-can-i-share-data-between-steps-features)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @gunr2171, but that article didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, but did you check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032996/specflow-steps-with-await-for-async-api)?

The key part is the comments:

Ensure that your method signature is `async Task`, not `async void`

```
[Given(@"I access the users route (.*)")]
public async Task GivenIAccessTheUsersRoute(string baseUrl)
//           ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Wynn! That was what was missing. As soon as I changed the **void** by **Task** the tests passed.

Comment: Just loose 3 hours looking for how my code can deadlock in xunit. Read every article I found and recode each testing class I used.
I just love you @Andrew